# laravel installation error in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, installation, ubuntu-16.04

I am having trouble while installation error in laravel.
First install xampp in ubuntu 16.04.
After that

```
cd /opt/lampp/htdocs/
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog
```

installation laravel with composer some error occurs

```
E: Package 'php5-mcrypt' has no installation candidate
shwekayin@shwekayin-VirtualBox:/opt/lampp/htdocs$ composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog1
Installing laravel/laravel (v5.3.0)
  - Installing laravel/laravel (v5.3.0)
    Loading from cache

Created project in blog1
> php -r "file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');"
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - laravel/framework v5.3.4 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.3.3 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.3.2 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.3.1 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.3.0 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for laravel/framework 5.3.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.3.0, v5.3.1, v5.3.2, v5.3.3, v5.3.4].

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in those .ini files:
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

How can I fix this error. My xampp php version is 7.0.10

Answer (score 3):

The error message details what is wrong:

> laravel/framework v5.3.4 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.

Run `sudo apt install php-mbstring` to install it.

Answer (score 0):

Run this

```
sudo apt-get install php libapache2-mod-php php-mcrypt php-mysql
```

if you no need to update php 7 again, Just run this

```
sudo apt-get install php-mcrypt
```

Install optional components these as well

```
libnet-libidn-perl - Perl bindings for GNU Libidn
php-all-dev - package depending on all supported PHP development packages
php-cgi - server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (CGI binary) (default)
php-cli - command-line interpreter for the PHP scripting language (default)
php-common - Common files for PHP packages
php-curl - CURL module for PHP [default]
php-dev - Files for PHP module development (default)
php-gd - GD module for PHP [default]
php-gmp - GMP module for PHP [default]

sudo apt-get install package_name
```

Best ever tutorial [How To Install Linux, Apache, MySQL, PHP (LAMP) stack on Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04) -used and works for me

Comment: Problem 1
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.5.4 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.5.3 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.

Answer (score 0):

By default Ubuntu 16.04 has php7.0 installed. You need to install first php5 (in your case here). And then switch to php5 before reinstalling laravel.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/756879/cant-install-php5-on-ubuntu-16-04